# Right way for embedding HTML into PHP

Tags: php, html

I have a define.php page that has many variables in it. I use to include in any other PHP file I make.

There is a variable named `$encodingdeclaration` which has `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">`.

The script now is becoming unresponsive: that because of an extra semicolon used after `text/html`, What to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`meta http-equiv` should be moved to .htaccess file
Adding it inline the way you do will cause html validating to fail.

If its a html5 page, simply add the below **before** your [title] tag

```
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
```

Also use double quotes for strings such as these.

```
$encodingdeclaration = "<meta charset=\"UTF-8\" />";
```

Comment: does this mean I don't need to move `meta http-equiv` to .htaccess file if opt to use HTML5?

Answer (score 0):

I can't really tell without you providing the actual code, but make sure that you're using single quotes around your string, since double quotes might conflict.  A semi-colon will not have any impact as long as it's properly enclosed in a string.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
$encodingdeclaration = '<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />';
```